# How do I pass records from Marketing Cloud to the Lead object in Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data

I am relatively new to Marketing cloud and I cannot seem to find a way in the documentation to get information from Marketing Cloud to Salesforce.

I would like to be able to have Marketing Cloud somehow create a Lead in Salesforce through the connector.

I know that data can be passed from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud but I cannot figure out the other way around.

Any advice would be amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the studio/builder in marketing cloud you want to use to create the lead object. This can for example be done using a journey builder activity or using an AMPscript function, as described below.

**Journey Builder**

Within a journey you can do this using the [Sales & Service Cloud Lead Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/sales_and_service_cloud_canvas_activities/legacy_activities/lead/).

**AMPscript**

To create a lead using AMPscript, you can use the function `CreateSalesforceObject(1,2,3,4)` which is explained in the [AMPscript Syntax Guide](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/createsalesforceobject/)